Need help remembering 80s or 90s movie action movie
I have recentenly been thinking about a movie I watched quite a few years ago. I don't remember anything about the plot, I believe it involed a mix of soldiers and civilians, but I can remember 2 scenes:

A female member of the team had to swim in tank used to cool a nuclear reactor ultimately dying. (I believe this scene takes place near the end of the film, but I am not sure)
One of the last scenes the male lead soldier and the female civilian kiss (yes I know this is a typical end of movie scene, sorry I can't be more specific)

The film was in english and likely American. 

Can you think of anything else to add to the description? Even trivial points (like appearance of an actor, costumes etc.) might help.
